# Convert a list of dicts to DataFrame and back to exactly same list?

Tags: python, json, django, pandas, dataframe

In my Django view, I want to load a list of dictionaries into a Pandas dataframe, manipulate it, dump to dict again and return such manipulated data **as a part** of this view's JSON response:

```
def test(request):
    pre_pandas = [{'type': 'indoor', 'speed': 1, 'heart_rate': None}, {'type': 'outdoor', 'speed': 2, 'heart_rate': 124.0}, {'type': 'commute', 'speed': 3, 'heart_rate': 666.0}, {'type': 'indoor', 'speed': 4, 'heart_rate': 46.0}]

    df = pd.DataFrame(pre_pandas)

    # some data manipulation here...

    post_pandas = df.to_dict(orient='records')

    response = {
        'pre_pandas': pre_pandas,
        'post_pandas': post_pandas,
    }

    return JsonResponse(response)
```

The problem with my approach is that Pandas' `to_dict()` method replaces Python's `None` with `nan`, so that the response has `NaN` in it:

```
 {"pre_pandas": [{"type": "indoor", "speed": 1, "heart_rate": null}...], "post_pandas": [{"heart_rate": NaN, "speed": 1,...}]
```

and JavaScript cannot tackle `NaN`.

Is there a way to dump a dataframe to a dict so that the output is exactly the same as the dict it was build from?

I could possibly adjust the data manually with a list `replace()` method, but it feels awkward and also I would need to cover for all of the other - if any - conversions Pandas' `to_dict()` method might do.

I also cannot dump `post_pandas` to JSON, as I am already doing it in `JsonResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

Your the columns in your pre_pandas Dataframe are inferred from the provided dictionary, to prevent this you can explicitly specify the data type object. What forces all the values to be of type object.

Like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pre_pandas, dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I cannot read numerical data as strings because I actually need to perform some calculations.

Comment: The problem you have here is that 'None' itself is not an float object representation. Thats why it is converted to np.NaN to be conform with the dtype of the heart_rate column. Otherwise you would end up with a mixed type column. 
To overcome this, you either use a custom dtype that allows that behaviour or you convert the column to float (what is done implicitly by the conversion to a Dataframe) and reformat the column afterwards (for example with replace).